# Raspberry stuck in PyCharm User Agreement

Tags: linux

Ive downloaded an extracted Pycharm on my Raspberry Pi. The problem is, when i start the pycharm.sh script, the pycharm user agreement window appears, but stays stuck with a lightblue background.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked through the pycharm.sh script?  Perhaps you can comment out that part.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add details about the Raspberry Pi model, OS and version and from where you downloaded pycharm. (It is not necessary to create a new user if you want to answer your own question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.
I added “-Dsun.java2d.xrender=false“
to the following file:
pycharm-community-2022.1.1/bin/pycharm64.vmoptions

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009415019-Unable-to-accept-JetBrains-Privacy-Policy-I-get-red-box-in-CentOS7-over-RDP

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).